# Cannot set languages layout for physical keyboard on Poco X3 Pro running Android 11

Tags: settings, keyboard, external-keyboard, android-11

I'm using Poco X3 Pro on Android 11. Looks like the settings are not been saved: after return and back to this screen I see previous settings:

[image: Android 11 physical keyboard layout]

I recorded it on the video https://youtu.be/DqTfHhv3Ot0

Comment: Try deleting the cache of keyboard app and then save

Comment: Stack Exchange requires the questions to be self-contained without depending on external sites. Please [edit] the question and transcribe the video as possible as you can.

Comment: @AndrewT. described